# c++ const ref vs template concept

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm studying the c++20 specifications for templates, in detail the concepts.

Currently for passing parameters to functions I use the const ref:

```
void writeMsg(const std::string& msg) {
  std::cout << "msg = " << msg << "\n";
}
```

I have only now discovered that templates can also be used, and with concepts I can control the parameters passed. Example:

```
template<typename T>
concept is_string = std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value;

template<is_string T>
void writeMsg2(T&& msg) {
  std::cout << "msg =" << msg << "\n";
}
```

Personally I can't understand the benefits, maybe my case is wrong to get the benefits from the concepts? Do you have any suggestions or links to help me in this question?

Thanks

Comment: What **is** the question? "Is my example a good example (it doesn't help me understand the advantage)?" is kind of self-answering. But I think you have a more precise, pressing question – I'm just not quite sure what that is.

Comment: Also not that your `writeMsg` takes `const &` of some type, so an lvalue reference, whereas your `writeMsg2` takes an rvalue reference – not quite the same thing!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Isn't that a forwarding reference in `writeMsg2`? So it could be const lvalue or lvalue or rvalue depending on how it's instantiated.

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller, thanks for the reply. it seems to me that with the concepts everything becomes "complicated" when with the const ref everything seems more readable. Is the use of concepts with the passing of parameters as above a wrong practice? Is the use of concepts wasted with the "elementary" use I make of them in my examples?

Comment: it's not more complicated. You're just using a different type of parameters. You're adding rvalue references to your confusion about concepts, even if they are separate things!

Comment: @NathanPierson Don't think it is; looks like a pretty classic case of "only implementing a function with `T&&`, but not `T&` nor `const T&` renders it unusable with lvalues", wait,

Comment: @NathanPierson http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_03.html

Comment: @MarcusMüller Read [a few pages further](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html)

Comment: My doubt is about `const&` I can use all type the parameters that I want: lvalue and rvalue. Next code works fine:


`    writeMsg("hi");
    std::string w{"hi"};
    writeMsg(w);
    writeMsg(std::move(w));`


Reading and watching dedicated videos it seems that they recommended the use of templates with && parameters. Here all my doubts.

Comment: The advantage of using *a* template is that a caller can pass in a `string_view` if he wants a string literal or a substring of another string object.  Just because `const string&` *can* bind, implicitly (no additional source code), to a temporary `string` instance created on-the-fly does not mean creation of the temporary is free.  (Note: the template and specifically the `is_string` concept shown in the question may not have this performance benefit, but there exists template code that does)

Comment: Testing convertibility and then not performing the conversion is weird. The second example would shine if you created a string from the parameter: it wouldn't copy the string unlike the first example (and even if you add a `&&` overload to the first example, the template version would still do less moves in some scenarios, like `writeMsg2("foo")`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you presented it: types which are convertible to `std::string` wouldn't need to be converted before the call to `std::cout` (potentially saving memory [de]allocations).
It's the only big advantage I can see looking at your code. However, flipping a bit or two:

```cpp
template <class T>
concept String = std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value;

void writeMsg2(String auto const& msg) {
  std::cout << "msg = " << msg << "\n";
}
```

[Live on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:19),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Anamespace+%7B%0Atemplate+%3Cclass+T%3E%0Aconcept+String+%3D+std::is_convertible%3CT,+std::string%3E::value%3B%0A%0Avoid+writeMsg2(String+auto+const%26+msg)+%7B%0A++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22msg+%3D+%22+%3C%3C+msg+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A++std::clog.put(!%27%5Cn!%27)+%3C%3C+__PRETTY_FUNCTION__%3B%0A%7D%0A%7D+//+namespace+(anonymous)%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++using+namespace+std::literals%3B%0A++::writeMsg2(%22std::string+(not+small+enough+to+get+SSOed+away)%22s)%3B%0A++::writeMsg2(%22Not+std::string%22)%3B+//+no+std::string+construction%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:54.840514829322885,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1400,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%270%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Weverything+-Wno-c%2B%2B98-compat-pedantic+-Wno-c99-compat++%27,paneName:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0%27,t:%270%27),(h:flags,i:(compilerFlags:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Weverything+-Wno-c%2B%2B98-compat-pedantic+-Wno-c99-compat++%27,compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,paneName:Flags,treeid:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:Flags,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:49.99999999999999,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:49.99999999999999,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:45.159485170677115,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Just because `std::string` has a stream insertion operator and a type is convertible to `std::string` does not mean that type has a stream insertion operator. There's no point of checking for convertibility to `std::string` if you're not going to actually perform that conversion.